# submit form after form after each other in html

Tags: html, forms

I have two different forms in html and want to have them come after each other instead of being displayed on the page at the same time. Honestly, I don't even know if you can have two form tags. I am pretty new to html so please nothing two advanced Thanks

I tried two form tags and added IDs then in the javascript I called the element in a function and at the end of the fist form when the button is clicked the next function containing the id of the second form is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way, when you load the page, only the first form will be visible. After clicking the "Next" button in the first form, it will hide, and the second form will become visible

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Two Forms Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <!-- Form 1 Fields -->
        <label for="field1">Field 1:</label>
        <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1">
        <button type="button" onclick="showForm2()">Next</button>
    </form>

    <form id="form2" style="display: none;">
        <!-- Form 2 Fields -->
        <label for="field2">Field 2:</label>
        <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2">
        <button type="submit">Submit Form 2</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        function showForm2() {
            // Hide form 1
            document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none";
            // Show form 2
            document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example:

The second form `form2` is initially hidden using inline CSS `style="display: none;"`

The "Next" button in the first form `form1` calls the `showForm2()` JavaScript function when clicked.

The `showForm2()` function hides `form1` and displays `form2` by changing their `style.display` properties.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue you have to use javascript, as it is a logic which you implementing in your website
As you said, you are executing the form on click of button using javascript, but that's a wrong approach
You can show the initial form (hide the other form) and then on click of button you can unhide the other and vice versa

```
const form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
const form2 = document.getElementById('form2');
```

And then once the first form is submitted you can unhide the form2 and hide the initial one

```
form1.style.display = 'none';
form2.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Thanks! so you just put that in a function and then call the function using button in HTML form tag

Comment: yeah you have to call the function to hide/unhide

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="form1">
    <!-- Form 1 content -->
    <input type="text" id="inputForm1" />
    <button type="button" onclick="submitForm1()">Form 1</button>
</form>

<form id="form2" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Form 2 content -->
    <input type="text" id="inputForm2" />
    <button type="button" onclick="submitForm2()">Form 2</button>
</form>

<script>
    function submitForm1() {
        //  Form 1 
        var inputForm1Value = document.getElementById("inputForm1").value;
        console.log("Form 1  value: " + inputForm1Value);

        // Display Form 2 , hide Form 1
        document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "block";
    }

    function submitForm2() {
        //  Form 2 
        var inputForm2Value = document.getElementById("inputForm2").value;
        console.log("Form 2 value: " + inputForm2Value);
       
    }
</script>
```